# How to make React objects unnecessary for any declarations with Visual studio 2019 Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have created a Typescript program in a Visual Studio 2019 nodejs project, but if I do not include the following declaration, it will cause an error if I use the setState method or this.props.

```
export default class ReduxTest extends React.Component {
    props: any;
    state: any;
    setState: any;
...
```

The types folder is located directly under the project. Within the Types folder, there is a definition file, react.d.ts. So I do not know how to set tsconfig.json.
The settings of tsconfig.json are as follows.

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
     "module": "es2015",
     "target": "esnext",
     "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "dom"],
     "jsx": "react",
     "alwaysStrict": true,
     "removeComments": true,
     "preserveConstEnums": true,
     "sourceMap": true,
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "types": ["node"],
     "baseUrl": "./",
     "outDir": "./dist"

   },
   "include": [
     "server.ts",
     "src / ** / *"
   ],
   "exclude": [
     "node_modules",
     "** / *. spec.ts"
   ]
}
```

How can Visual Studio complete it and make React component declaration unnecessary?

Comment: Can you install `@types/react`?

Comment: Sorry, It cannot resolve this

Comment: I can resolve to install  types/react and change statement and declaration.　Thank  you.

Answer (score 2):

React class components must either extend `React.Component` or be created with `createReactClass()`; this is how they inherit the underlying functionality of React class components (state, lifecycle hooks, etc). This is not syntactic sugar that comes from Typescript.

You can read more about the differences between the two [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html).

Comment: Does that mean that createReactClass () might solve this problem? However, it is better to use React.Componet by inheriting it.Thus, Should I give up solving this problem.

Comment: @tierailgun I think you can use one or the other, but the convention is to extend `React.Component`. My point is that I don't think it is a problem; this is simply how the Javascript language works.

Comment: I want not to declear   under statement. But it is Javascript language works. 
"ex:    props: any; state: any;  setState: any; "